# why from unbounded wildcard <?> to <? extends Object> does not generate an unchecked conversion warning?

Tags: java, generics

Think i ask this question before but still don't understand to a certain degree.

1. From raw to <?> - no unchecked conversion warning. Understood since both are reifiable type.
2. From raw to <? extends Object> - unchecked conversion warning. Understood since <? extends Object> is a non reifiable type.
3. From <?> to <? extends Object> - no unchecked conversion warning. Why? Since the former is a reifiable type and the latter is not. I see this as similiar to clause 2.

Answer (score 3):

`<?>` and `<? extends Object>` are actually the same thing, and should be interchangeable.

Actually, since `List<? extends Object>` is a super type of `List<?>` (vice versa), if it's safe to convert `List` to `List<?>`, it should also be safe to convert `List` to `List<? extends Object>`.

The spec requires unbounded wildcard `<?>` in some places, while the twin brother `<? extends Object>` is not mentioned (therefore forbidden). There's no theoretical reason for that; the language designers probably reasoned that `<?>` is enough for practical use cases.

For example, in 5.1.9 *Unchecked Conversion*, converting raw `G` to `G<T1..Tn>` generates a mandatory compile-time warning unless all `Ti=?`. This is a little too harsh; a counter example:

```
class G<N extends Number>{}

G x = ...;
G<? extends Number> y = x; //warning, tho absolutely safe
```

the conversion from x to y is safe, and the warning is really unnecessary.

It is possible to relax the rule to exempt all safe conversions. 
We know it is safe to convert raw `G` to `G<?..?>`; furthermore, if `G<T1..Tn>` is a super type of `G<?..?>`, converting `G` to `G<T1..Tn>` is also safe, and should be allowed without warning. This certainly makes sense.

However, checking that `G<?..?>` is a subtype of `G<T1..Tn>` is not a trivial task; the language designer probably said, to hell with it, it's not worth the trouble to do this for unchecked conversion, which is not an important part of the type system anyway.

Comment: But the point is <?> is reifiable and <? extends Object> is not. I see contradiction here based on your explanation

Comment: that means the definition of "reifiable type" is also incomplete. certainly type `List<? extends Object>` is "completely available at run time" - given a runtime 'List' object, it is definitely also a `List<? extends Object>` (which is equivalent to `List<?>`). Since 2 types are equivalent of each other, except for the syntax, treating them as semantically different is not an ideal thing to do.

Comment: That's not what i understood. List <? extends Object> is not reifiable. All bounded wildcard (which means excluding unbounded wildcard) will be erased and will not be reifiable. So <?> is not the same as <? extends Object>. I verified this with lots of SCJP books.

Comment: `<?>` is also erased. at runtime there's only raw `List`; nevertheless, we can reason that it must be `List<?>` as well as `List<? extends Object>`. the spec is flawed, that's all.

Comment: so are you saying that <? extends Object> is reifiable?

Comment: it is not, per spec. but the spec is flawed. it should have been. we can't talk about the wildcard alone; a wildcard is not a type by itself. the more complicated story is this: if `G<T1..Tn>` is a super type of `G<?..?>`, it must be true that `G<T1..Tn>=G<?..?>` the two are equivalent; any object of raw `G` must be of type `G<T1..Tn>`. so `G<T1..Tn>` should be reifiable too, ideally. If it is, you wouldn't observe the contradiction as in your question.

Comment: I have requested this thread to be removed multiple times but nothing happens .. Frustrated cos' i want to clean my questionaires

Comment: @yapkm01 We don't delete questions for no reason.  People spent time answering, so it might be useful to others in the future.

Comment: I appreciate all the answers given by people who took the time to look at my problem. From the bottom of my heart i say thanks. But i just don't find those answer really answered my questions. That's why i thought it's better to have this remove

Answer (score 0):

`<?>` means it can be any subtype.

Every subtype of that will always extend Object.

I believe you wouldn't have a problem if you went from `<? extends Number>` to `<? extends Object>` either.